# Checking the Last 2 days of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to check what are the bookings in the last 2 days of each month, I already did for the last day but I gives me some wrong data, and I need to expand it to get not only the last day but also the last 2 days of each month

```
SELECT Debit, Amount, Posted_Date, Posted_Time, Posted_By
FROM [dbo].[Test_data]
WHERE Booking_date IN (
        SELECT MAX(Booking_date)
        FROM [dbo].[Test_data]
        GROUP BY MONTH(Booking_date), YEAR(Booking_date)
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you all the bookings made on the last 2 days of the month of booking. It won't work if booking_date stores time.

```
SELECT Debit, Amount, Posted_Date, Posted_Time, Posted_By
FROM [dbo].[Test_data]
WHERE Booking_date between 
  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Booking_date) + 1, 0) - 2  AND
  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Booking_date) + 1, 0) - 1
```

If you are storing time on booking_date:

```
SELECT Debit, Amount, Posted_Date, Posted_Time, Posted_By
FROM [dbo].[Test_data]
WHERE Booking_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Booking_date) + 1, 0) - 2  AND
      Booking_date < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Booking_date) + 1, 0)
```

Comment: if I want to specify a time for ex. 2015.03.03 22:00 and 2015.03.04 05:00 o'clock , i mean the booking is happening in between this time beside the date change after 00:00 oclock.

Comment: @Chis I'm sorry I don't understand. Do you want to check if booking is between the third day of the month at 22:00 and 4th day at 5am?

Comment: I got the Posted_Time and it specifies the time stamp, and i want to get all the bookings between 22:00 - 05:00 o'clock the 7 hours, but this will include date change!

Comment: something like `posted_time between dateadd(HH,22,cast(cast(Posted_Time as date) as datetime)) and
       dateadd(HH,29,cast(cast(Posted_Time as date) as datetime))`

Comment: ya but Posted_Time is not a date , its form like 07:21:42.0000000

Comment: `cast('2001-01-01' as datetime) + Posted_Time between  dateadd(HH,22,cast('2001-01-01' as datetime)) and
       dateadd(HH,5,cast('2001-01-02' as datetime))`

Answer (score 0):

One more approach is using  a [calendar table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/30/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/) ,once you have calendar table which looks like below,then it is very easy to get all the info

[image]

Above  calendar table gives me the required dates all you have to do  is join next

```
select t1.* from
dbo.testdate t1
join
(select date from calendar
where date>=convert(datetime,dateadd(day,-1,LDtOfMo))  and year=2013
) c
on c.date=t1.booking_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a new date function named [SQL EOMonth() for calculating end of month](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/end-of-month-eomonth-function-in-sql-server-2012.aspx)

```
EOMONTH (getdate())
```

After you get the end of month, you can use following for the day before

```
DATEADD(dd,-1,@eomonth_date)
```

Comment: Yes, that's much better if you are on SQL Server 2012. It's not clear in the tagging